# UTF-8 File Validity

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I have a text file that I opened in Notepad++ (Encoding is in UTF-8) that like this :

[image: File]

However, when I copied that line and paste into anywhere (a new tab, or even here), I get this :

`Тиѐ°я установка`

As such, I am rather confused - is this a valid UTF8 file/line?

If not, why is it when I copied the line and paste it somewhere else, it seems/looks okay?

Comment: The file is apparently not valid UTF-8. But when copying to the clipboard, you’re copying *text*, so that invalid file needs to be interpreted *somehow* to *something* that is valid and copiable.

Comment: @deceze i tried converting the file into utf8 via ```iconv```  but encountered error. what should I do if I need to process these files (user submissions) via a script (stores this entries in a database)? is this a bad submission or can i still salvage the file?

Comment: The fact that Notepad++ is showing you the `xD1` in a different style than the rest of the text is a dead give-away that the file is not encoded properly. There is likely no chance of salvaging the file as-is, you need to figure out why the file is encoded incorrectly and fix THAT instead.